# Relating $0$'s of a continuous function with limits at $\pm \infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, roots

let $f$ be a continuous function defined in $\mathbb{R}$.

If

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow + \infty} f(x) = l > 0
$$

can I say that there's an $\tilde{x} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(\tilde{x}) > 0$?
My guess is yes, because by the definition of limit

$$
\forall \epsilon>0 \exists x_0 : \forall x > x_0 \; |f(x) - l|<\epsilon
$$
specifically
$$
\forall \epsilon>0 \exists x_0 : \forall x > x_0 \; -\epsilon < f(x) - l <\epsilon
$$

For $\epsilon = l$ I specifically have

$$
\exists x_0 : \forall x > x_0 -l < f(x) - l \Rightarrow \exists x_0 : \forall x > x_0 \; f(x) > 0
$$

Which means I can pick an $\tilde{x} > 0$ such that $f(\tilde{x}) > 0$.

Two further questions If this is true I assume that if

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow - \infty} f(x) = l < 0
$$

I can say that there's an $\tilde{x} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(\tilde{x}) < 0$, is that right?

Combining both

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
\lim_{x\rightarrow - \infty} f(x) = l_{-} < 0 \\
\lim_{x\rightarrow + \infty} f(x) = l_{+} > 0
\end{array}
\end{equation}

I can then say there's an interval $A = [x_{-},x_{+}]$ such that for some $\tilde{x} \in A$ we have $f(\tilde{x}) = 0$.

Is that right?

Comment: It's all quite right! Well done!

Comment: Is this a well know result that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I'd say that the two steps 
1) if $f$ has both a positive and negative limit on $\mathbb{R}$, then it has both positive and negative values (by the definition of limit) and
2) if $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and assumes both positive and negative values then it's $0$ somewhere (by the intermediate value theorem/ Bolzano's theorem)
are so commonly used that ... it's not quite a well known result, but it's a well recognized result :)
Bonus: a) Which other values can you prove that $f$ assumes under your conditions? b) Can you find an $f$ that assumes *only* the values you proved in a)?

Comment: a) Any value in $(l_{-},l_{+})$ by the intermediate value theorem b) $f(x) = l_{-} + (l_{+}-l{-})\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$, are those right?

Comment: Yes, well done!